# npm install from a git repo leaves a pretty blank package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

I am using working from this [github issue](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/621) and it says to use a temporary github fork until a pull request is merged in another repo....cool.

I try to add the github fork to my project dependencies by doing this...

```
    "reactstrap": "git+https://github.com/jameswomack/reactstrap.git",
```

in the `package.json` file and when I do a `npm install` everything goes according to plan, but then I get failures with my project not being able to find `reactstrap`...

When I go to inspect my `node_modules` I can see that the reactrap directory is pretty empty with only the `LICENSE`, `README` and `package.json` files...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12):

The *package.json* file of the repository contains these lines:

```
"files": [
    "LICENSE",
    "README.md",
    "CHANGELOG.md",
    "lib",
    "dist"
]
```

This is the list of files and directories to include in the npm package. As you can see, the actual JavaScript files will be located in the `lib` and `dist` directories.

The problem is that these directories are not checked into the Git repository, but created by a build, when you run `npm run build`.

A workaround that I would try: run the build, commit and push the generated files to your fork on GitHub. After that, installing the dependency the way you do it should give you the desired result.

**However**, if your goal is simply to test if your changes on a local fork of `reactstrap` work by including it as a dependency of a demo project, there is a better way: use [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

It works like this:

- in the root of your local clone of your `reactstrap` fork, execute the command `npm link`
- in the root of your demo project that uses `reactstrap` as dependency, execute the command `npm link reactstrap`

Any changes you then do to your `reactstrap` fork will be available in your demo project immediately.